# Остолоп и столп - однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, лексика, словообразование, семантика

Последние дни что-то часто стала обращаться к этимологическим словарям и вдруг обнаружила, что столб, столп, остолоп - однокоренные.

Как получилось, что **остолоп** (глупец, болван) и **столп** (выдающийся человек, видный деятель) - исторически однокоренные слова? Хотелось бы увидеть механизм изменения значений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Взбудоражен, вечно встрепан,*
>
> *Среди всех шатаясь толп,*
>
> *В личной жизни остолоп он,*
>
> *А в общественной он столп.*

А может, через исторический словарь попробовать подобраться?

> [**Столб**](http://endic.ru/history/Stolb-39017.html)
>
> — то же, что истукан, кумир, изображение божества (Исх 34.13; Лев
> 26.1; Иез 6.4), которые, по-видимому, часто устраивались на столбах (подставках) или в виде столбов. *(См. дерево посвященное, дубрава)*, -

вот нам и разъяснение столпу общества.

[**Столб**](http://endic.ru/rusethy/Stolb-4279.html)

> Общеслав. Родственно латышск. ***stulbs «столб»***, др.-исл. ***stolpi
> «столб»*** и т. д. Корень тот же, что в ***столп***.

А выдающегося деятеля-столпа Ибсен придумал (так я разобралась), но он подтрунивает, взывая к тому, что возвышается благодаря подставке:

**[Столпы общества](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/2619/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BF%D1%8B)**

> С норвежского: Samfundets stotter.
>
> Название пьесы (1877) норвежского
> драматурга Генрика Ибсена (1828—1906), в которой автор показывает
> состоятельных и уважаемых граждан маленького провинциального городка
> Норвегии, внешне респектабельных, но внутренне ущербных.
>
> ***Иронически***: о людях, которые занимают высокое положение в обществе и в силу этого ***якобы*** хранят его мораль и традиции.
>
> Энциклопедический словарь крылатых слов и выражений. — М.:
> «Локид-Пресс». Вадим Серов. 2003.

А Фасмер и вовсе разыгрался, через "б" пишет и отсылает к *ослопу*:

> **[остоло́п](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D0%BE/%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF)** диал. остоло́б — то же, уржумск. (Шахматов, Очерк 281). От столп, столб (Соболевский, РФВ 64, 124; Маценауэр, LF 12, 174
> и сл.; Перссон 426). Ср. поле́но, дуби́на, чурба́н и др. в качестве
> ругательств (Преобр. I, 665). См. осло́п.

Честно ищем ослопа:

> **[осло́п](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BE/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF)** род. п. -о́па «дубина, кругляк», «дурак», с.-в.-р., вост.,
> русск., ослопи́на «длинная жердь», осло́пье — то же, др.-русск. ослопъ
> «дубина, палка» (Жит. Стеф. Перм. и др.; Срезн. II, 725 и сл.),
> ослопа́н «остолоп, чурбан», арханг. (Подв.). Обычно относят вместе с
> остоло́п (см.) к столп; см. Соболевский, РФВ 64, 124; Преобр. I, 663.

Подытоживая. ***Выдающийся деятель с течением времени утратил исторические кавычки***; был дубиной стоеросовой, стал таким сурьёзным, всамделишным...

Comment: Браво, Галина! Вот что значит читать исторические словари! Остолоп - дубина, чурбан; столп - то же самое, но возвышается над всеми, а внутри пустое. Столп в архитектуре -  высокая башня, крестообразное перекрытие, поддерживающее свод храма(шатровый вид), полая колонна. Потом появился религиозный столп = знамя в значении "нотный знак в песнопениях" православия, похожий на столп, его внутр. содержание - высокая духовность. Значения объединились. Теперь столп - тот же возвышающийся столб, но с высок. внутренним содержанием, а остолоп - само по себе, со сниж. оценкой.

Answer (score 2):

В этимологическом словаре [Г. А. Крылова](https://krylov.lexicography.online/%D0%BE/%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF):
**остоло́п**
Значение этого слова станет понятнее, если мы скажем, что образовано оно от исчезнувшего из языка глагола *о**столп**ети*, означавшего «остолбенеть», «стать столбом от удивления»; остолоп, столп, столб — все слова одного корня, в котором чередуются гласные и согласные. Таким образом, остолоп буквально — «остолбеневший, застывший от удивления».

В этимологическом словаре [А. Ситникова](https://etymology_ru.academic.ru/3020):
**остолоп**
Собств.-р. Образовано от *остьлп`кти* — «стать столбом от изумления или страха», производного от *стълпъ* — «столб». Ср. подобное и родственное диал. *остолбен*ъ — «остолоп» (откуда остолбенеть).

Остолоп — *устар. спец.* дерево со сломанной верхушкой (то есть "голый" ствол, почти как столб).

**Дополнение**

Из словаря Т. Ф. Ефремовой:
**столп**
**I.** *м. устар.*
Колонна, поддерживающая своды, перекрытия.
Памятник в виде колонны, воздвигаемый в честь какого-либо события. [Александрийский столп]
**II.** *м.* Выдающийся деятель, являющийся **надежной опорой чего-либо.**

Я думаю, что последнее значение переносное: так говорят о человеке, "на котором всё держится" (см. первую формулировку) , о человеке, который является основоположником в науке или искусстве.

*Я не говорю о Пушкине, Лермонтове, Жуковском, это столпы нашей литературы.*

[У Ожегова: столп — *устар. высок. и ирон.* о выдающемся деятеле.]

Comment: Значение слова "остолоп" я понимаю. А при чём здесь столп в значении "выдающийся деятель?" Остолбенеть - остолпеть  используется значение столб - колонна. И синоним остолопа болван тоже понятен - болванами языческих идолов называли, каменных или деревянных истуканов, их делали из болванок - заготовок. Не все же столбы являются столпами, вот Александровская колонна - Александрийский столп, а провода держатся на столбах, хоть иногда и каменных. Почему?

Comment: Ну, все же очень понятно: столп (столб) -- это то, на что можно смотреть снизу вверх, на что можно опираться и т.п. Отсюда уже рукой подать до выдающегося деятеля. Столп -- архаизм (может, он и во времена Пушкина был архаизмом?), а архаизмы часто тяготеют к высокому штилю.

Comment: Да, во времена Пушкина столп - уже архаизм, в древнерусском были и столб, и столп, может, столп - из ст.-слав., потому и устарело в значении "столб".